# Insert/Update Stored Procedure has conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, getdate

I am trying to make one stored procedure only in SQL Server that lets the user to choose if he/she wants to add or update a record. Below is my code for my stored pro:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sproc_INSERTUPDATE_tblProducts

    @ProductID bigint,
    @ProductName varchar(50),
    @Description varchar(50),
    @Price money,
    @DateCreated datetime,
    @DateUpdated datetime,
    @Choice bit output

AS
BEGIN

    Select @Choice
    If @Choice = 0
    Begin
    Insert into tblProducts (
                          ProductID, 
                          ProductName, 
                          Description, 
                          Price, 
                          DateCreated, 
                          DateUpdated)
    values (@ProductID, 
                @ProductName, 
                @Description, 
                @Price, 
                @DateCreated, 
                @DateUpdated)
    Select * from tblProducts
    End
    Else If @Choice = 1
    Begin
    Update tblProducts Set ProductID = @ProductID,
                           ProductName = @ProductName,
                           Description = @Description,
                           Price = @Price,
                           DateCreated = @DateCreated,
                           DateUpdated = @DateUpdated
    Select * from tblProducts
    End
    Else
    Begin
    Print 'Invalid choice. Please choose 0 or 1 only.'
    End

END
GO
```

And here is my code for executing the stored pro I made:

```
USE StoreDB

Execute Sproc_INSERTUPDATE_tblProducts 4, 'Lotus', 'Flower', 85, GetDate, GetDate, 0
```

I don't encounter any errors with my stored pro but when I try to execute using a new query, I get this error message:

> GetDate(): Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

Comment: I don't understand "when I try to execute using a new query" - what's the query you're trying to execute? an insert/update? or a select (read back the data) query?

Comment: BTW, I don't think you need to declare `@Choice` as an Output parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass a function such as getdate() into a stored proc. Declare a datetime variable and use that instead.

```
Declare @now datetime = getdate();
Execute Sproc_INSERTUPDATE_tblProducts 4, 'Lotus', 'Flower', 85, @now, @now, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
Execute Sproc_INSERTUPDATE_tblProducts 4, 'Lotus', 'Flower', 85, GetDate(), GetDate(), 0
```